# How to store image from url to server folder using node js?

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am new to NodeJS and try to practice file upload from URL like this:

- I have One url on which one image is placed. I want to upload that image into my server without download it anywhere. How can I do that ?
- I tried node-fetch package to fetch buffer of image from URL and then try to write in my server using `createWriteStream` But failed.
- Please help me. I don't know what is the correct way to upload file.

### What I have tried :

```
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
import { pipeline } from 'stream';
import { promisify } from 'util'
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const streamPipeline = promisify(pipeline);
const response = await fetch('http://dummy.com/5.png');
if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`unexpected response ${response.statusText}`);
await streamPipeline(response.body, createWriteStream('./img.png'));
```